# Cómo muestro un cartel mientras está mal el input

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Mi problema es que no puedo o no sé mostrar un cartel que me pida corregir un campo del formulario.

Yo estoy usando este método pero no me funciona:

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="carga">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreaer" minlength="8" required ng-model="nombreaer" placeholder="Nombre">
  <label for="nombreaer" ng-show="carga.nombreaer.$invalid">Ingrese el nombre correctamente</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola Maxi Albert, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español (no te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Una duda: ¿qué versión de angular estás usando? (no sé si es importante, pero quizás lo sea). También, esto es algo que se puede hacer incluso sin Angular/JavaScript, sólo con HTML y CSS, ¿estarías abierto a una respuesta de ese tipo?

Comment: Muchas gracias por editar la pregunta para que quede correctamente en ortografia y compresion, estoy usando angularjs ultima version y si estoy abierto a la repuesta usando solamente HTML, en clases me enseñaron que con esa sintaxis, usando la directiva de angular, se simplificaba demasiado pero no veo que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Al código le faltan un par de cosas:

- Falta especificar la aplicación con `ng-app` (ésta me imagino que es mi culpa y que lo tienes bien en tu código, pero se me olvidó ponerlo en la demo porque no soy un experto en Angular).
- Falta darle un `name` al `input`. Los campos de formularios deben tener un atributo `name` (que es el que se manda al servidor). Parece que en la cadena `carga.nombreaer.$invalid`, ese `nombreaer` no es el `id` o el modelo sino el nombre del campo.

Una vez añades esas dos cosas que faltan, ya funciona sin problemas:

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="carga" ng-app="">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreaer" minlength="8" required ng-model="nombreaer" name="nombreaer" placeholder="Nombre">
  <label for="nombreaer" ng-show="carga.nombreaer.$invalid">Ingrese el nombre correctamente</label>
</form>
```

---

Alternativamente, y como te ponía en un comentario, esto también se podría hacer en HTML+CSS sin necesidad de JavaScript/Angular. Sería usando la pseudo-clase `:invalid` que te indica si un campo no es válido. Aquí lo puedes ver:

```css
input + label {
  display: none;
}

input:invalid + label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form name="carga">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreaer" minlength="8" required  name="nombreaer" placeholder="Nombre">
  <label for="nombreaer">Ingrese el nombre correctamente</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente! funciona perfectamente, entonces el segundo campo luego del nombre del formulario es el nombre del input y no el nombre del modelo, tiene mas logica si nos ponemos a pensar ya que debemos controlar el campo en si y no solamente el texto a escribir. doy por solucionada mi pregunta, es posible preguntar sobre una expresion regular que necesito?

Comment: @MaxiAlbert las preguntas sobre expresiones regulares entran dentro de la temática del sitio. Lo único es que tendrás que crear una nueva pregunta.